# EU Compliance for Drupal multidomain (each domain has its own language)

Tags: 7, cookies

We have developed a multidomain drupal project and each domain has its own language. In other words, each language has assigned its own domain.

When we have developed multilanguage sites we have not found any problem to use "EU Cookie compliance" module to show an specific configuration for each language: in fact, if we change "/en/" for "/es/" in URL we can configure its specific EU Compliance.

But, as we told you, this is not a multilanguage... it's a multidomain platform. Our problem is if we try to implemnt "EU cookie compliance" module for each domain we cannot change it because this module only show us main domain of platform.

Anybody knows how I can implement it an specific EU Compliance for each domain?